# Why botium-box HTTP(S)/JSON connector request is empty?

Tags: testing, flask, chatbot, botium-box

This is my demo code:

```
from flask import Flask , jsonify, request, render_template
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/t',methods=['GET','POST'])
def t():
    print(request.data)
    print (request.headers)
    return jsonify({"test":"test"})
if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host="0.0.0.0",port=5000)
```

When I use the Generic HTTP(S)/JSON Connector and to Click CHECK CONNECTIVITY Button,
it response a "test" for text.

but I see the logs , the header is empty. The logs is below:

```
192.168.58.119 - - [17/Aug/2020 15:24:35] "[37mGET /t HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
b''
Host: 192.168.58.145:5000
Connection: close
```

[The connectivity is successful.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeIRF.png)

How to get the botium box query text in the http headers?

thanks!

Comment: I want to get the query text in botium-box , then I can transfer this message to my own nlp web chatbot.

Comment: quickstart has only a limited set of config options for the connector. open the Chatbots menu, register a new chatbot and go to the settings section - there you can configure request body and headers

Comment: Thank for your assistance. I success to send message to my chatbot.  [https://i.imgur.com/daDOJIe.png](https://i.imgur.com/daDOJIe.png)